# What are good poker books from the last 4 years

Tags: books

I've been out of poker for a few years now. I was a winning @ NL100/200 and small stakes tourney. What would be a worthwhile read since 2015?

Comment: I don't think that there is anything note worthy that has come out in the last four years. If you still have a library I would suggest reviewing those might work best. A quick look at AMZ shows all the top rated books are pretty much classics now, with nothing newer then '15 making much impact.

Comment: The norm now are poker videos, not books.

Comment: Checkout Jonathan Little, he has some books from 2015/2016